How Can I Fully Isolate Dependencies Between Two Python Projects (with Editable Installation)?
Description
I have two Python projects with separate virtual environments:
Project A: Uses Python 3.9 and requires torch in a version not compatible with other dependencies on B.
Project B: Uses Python 3.12 and doesn't need torch, but it relies on some functions from A.
I would like to be able to use the Functions from A in B, also passing data arrays from B to A (therefore console arguments is not an option). ideally with pip install -e. Ideally A would use its own dependencies.
Problem
However, when I run Project B, it throws an error because, of course, torch isn’t installed in B's environment.
This is all in the same machine and both are my own code (curently on linux/windows and im trying to keep it OS-independent).
Approaches I’ve Considered:
Subprocess Call: Use subprocess in B to call scripts from A, while activating A's virtual environment for each call. This approach allows A to keep its own dependencies, but it feels like a workaround, especially when working with multiple calls or returning complex data, that i would have to serialize (extra steps, extra maintenance).
Service-Based Architecture: Convert A into a microservice using Flask or FastAPI. B would then communicate with A over HTTP. This seems like a good way to achieve complete isolation. This introduces additional complexity with networking.
Standalone Executable Script: Package A as an executable script that B can call independently, which would use A's virtual environment. However, it still requires handling CLI arguments and doesn’t support direct function calls.
Question
Are there any better approaches or best practices for fully isolating dependencies in this type of setup? Ideally, I’d like B to call functions from A directly without running into dependency conflicts. I’m open to restructuring or using different tools if there’s a cleaner or more efficient solution. Any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you!
